# How to get an "ends with" search in Solr 4.8.1?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a document, indexed on Solr, which contains this field:

```js
{
    "manufacturerSkuEndsWith": [
        "DU351118DR0"
    ]
}
```

My goal is to get an "ends with" search on the `manufacturerSkuEndsWith` field. For example, the following queries should match the value above: `DR0`, `8DR0`, `18DR0`, `118DR0`... but these queries should NOT match: `DU35`, `118DR`, `118`...

My problem is that the query `118` matches that document, even though `DU351118DR0` does not end with `118`.

My Solr & Lucene version is 4.8.1. I've found out that in this version the `side="back"` for the EdgeNGramTokenizer is not supported anymore: [LUCENE-3907](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3907). In this thread, they are suggesting to use a `ReverseStringFilter` to get a behaviour similar to an EdgeNGramTokenizer with `side="back"`, so this is how I configured the `manufacturerSkuEndsWith` field in my `schema.xml`:

```xml
<field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="manufacturerSkuEndsWith" stored="true" type="smccTextReversedNGram"/>

<copyField dest="manufacturerSkuEndsWith" source="ManufacturerSku"/>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="smccTextReversedNGram" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="3"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

but this configuration does not perform an "ends with" search:

[image: screenshot from the Solr analysis tool]

How can I get that type of search, instead?

Comment: You're using the `NGramTokenizer`, not the `EdgeNgramFilter` - the ngram tokenizer will generate tokens for each sub-part of the string, not just the end. Also the ticket explains that you should to reverse filter, edgengram, then reverse filter again (but doing the reverse filter on query as well would do the same). In your case; reverse filter, edgengram and then store.

Comment: @MatsLindh You solved my problem, thank you! Could you please post an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the NGramTokenizer and not the EdgeNGramFilter as shown in the examples. The NgramTokenizer will generate tokens from inside the string as well, and not just from the edge.

To get the behavior you're looking for you have to have a KeywordTokenizer (which will keep the input as a single token), and then use the ReverseStringFilter to reverse it - before using the EdgeNGramFilter to generate strings from the start of the now reversed string:

```
foo -> oof -> o, oo, oof
```

You can then either run these through the reversed string filter again to get the "correct" versions indexed:

```
-> o, oo, foo
```

.. or you can do as you've done in your field, and reverse the input string instead:

```
foo -> oof -> matches the oof token
```